# How to make an ahead of time compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am reading about compiler development and came across examples using llvm to emit something called object files (the ones that have an extension .o).

Then what most of the time happened was they used GCC to link and make the final executables.

What my question in a nutshell is that I have used compilers like rustc, golang's compiler and others which make the executable themselves and don't rely on GCC to link and assemble the object files, so how to do that ? Is there any library for linking object files and making native executables or does rust and go use GCC under the hood ?

Comment: rustc relies on linker. For example, on Windows objects files are linked by link.exe by default. However, there is LLVM linker if you like to use it: https://lld.llvm.org/

Comment: Okay. So I were to write a compiler, and generate some object files, how would I go about linking and assembling them into a native executable in an abstract way ?

Comment: Well, in very vague way it works in such steps: 1) run frontend of your compiler and generate LLVM IR files, 2) run llc for each of your IR files to generate object files, 3) run lld with all of them at once to generate final executable.

Comment: So llc and lld are required on the machine as dependencies of the compiler. Any way to embed them somehow into/with the compiler so that the user doesn't need to have anything installed/setup ?

Comment: I don't know, rust and free pascal managed it somehow. You, probably, can make an installer or something like that.

Comment: You can generate .o files (or the in-memory representation) in your own code, it's not terribly complicated. Linking your .o files into an executable involves linking with some per-platform files whose names and paths are a little more system-dependent than most people like, so the cheap way out of that is to ask gcc to do that chore for you. The gcc maintainers have fine tables of what .o/.a files are needed in order to start your main().

Comment: So if I were to release my compiler, I would have to list gcc x.x.x as a dependency that needs to be preinstalled on the machines where people download the compiler ? Cool!

Comment: @arnt could you tell how to generate .o files without using llvm ? Some other library perhaps ?

Comment: Oh, I do use LLVM, what I I don't use is llc/lld, see? LLVM offers classes and methods to create a .o file from a Module object. The code I use is 50-60 lines long, it could be a bit shorter but you know how it is. I think I've posted a variant of that code in an older SO question.

Comment: Actually there is some issue with llvm installer on my pc (windows) so i am looking for alternatives. If someone gives me a pre installed llvm tarball/zip, i'll definitely go your way, @arnt

Comment: Why doesn't anyone add a detailed answer ?

Comment: @arnt older SO question ? Where's the link ?

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't the time to search for the link for you, at least not today. Maybe next week. (And BTW, if I had to guess, "I have installer problems" makes people think that you require a great deal of details and help.)

Comment: @arnt No installer problems now. I got something called winlibs (https://winlibs.com/) that had clang, ld and a ton of other supposedly useful stuff which I will go through. And there's a LLVM.dll which I do think contains THE code generation classes which you spoke of and the linker library like the one Rust uses.